# Codemagic - Set Dynamic Environment Variables for the Build arguments

Tags: flutter, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, flutter-test, codemagic

I am looking a way to manage dynamic environment variables in my build arguments.

[image]

I am able to make it work if I define values for `TARGET_FILE` and `FLAVOR` in the environment variable section in CodeMagic. 
But my goal is to have the values specified in my git repository. So I will be able to change it and have a dynamic build.

I was thinking I would be able to set the env var in the pre-build section.

[image]

Following is a sample of my `pre-build.sh` file

```
# in my case it’s `dev`, `qa` and `prod`
export FLAVOR='qa'

# major and minor part of app version e.g. 1.0
export VERSION_NUMBER='1.0.0'

# this is the entry point of the app e.g. main_dev.dart
export TARGET_FILE="lib/main_$FLAVOR.dart"
```

My build is still failing because the `TARGET_FILE` for example is not specified

```
Target file "--flavor" not found.


Build failed :|
Failed to build for Android
```

I was wondering if anyone has ever encountered this scenario

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for configuring build from GitHub you can use `codemagic.yaml` file that allows you to define the configuration for CodeMagic build, including env variables ([here is a docs](https://docs.codemagic.io/building/yaml/#environment)).

**Additional notes, just a proposition))**

I actually don't know what is going on in your Flavors and env entry points, but quite possible you can actually get rid of both.

For instance, you can use .env file and [flutter_config](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_config) package to pass env specific variables to the native layer, including plist's and Gradle. Also, you can load this .env file into Dart code and use variables from it. On top of this, you can use [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/environment_config) to generate .env file with the terminal command (if you don't want to create any sh scripts))). Alongside with .env file, it can generate Dart class specifically for Dart code. It also can generate files based on [global env variables](https://github.com/TatsuUkraine/dart_environment_config#global-environment-variable-example).

In that way all environment specific configuration will be defined once, you won't expose your prod credentials anywhere except build tool and you won't need to copy/paste multiple entry points.

**Update 08/05/2020:**

Starting from Flutter 1.17 you can use `--dart-defines` argument instead of environment_config and flutter_config package to define compile-time variables. You can read more about this argument [here](https://medium.com/@tatsu.ukraine/flutter-1-17-no-more-flavors-no-more-ios-schemas-command-argument-that-solves-everything-8b145ed4285d)

Comment: I managed to do it using `codemagic.yaml`.  For this specific scenario, `codemagic.yaml` was enough , I didn't need to implement something with [flutter_config](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_config). But aware of it now. Thank you [tatusDn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10871399/tatusdn)